# Hyperledger Fabric-ca connection to a LDAP directory

Tags: ldap, openldap, hyperledger-fabric-ca

We are implementing a Hyperledger Fabric solution. To do so, we set up a fabric-CA, using the minimal configuration (we are still trying to figure out how the things works) in a specific docker.

As we need to login our users, using a email/password couple, we set up a LDAP component. We choosed to use OpenLDAP, using osixia/openldap implementation in a different docker.

We set the parameters in the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml to connect Fabric CA to the LDAP. At the start of both dockers, the logs seems fine :

```
Successfully initialized LDAP client
```

When we carry on the Fabric-CA tutorial, we fail at the command :

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://cn=admin,dc=example:admin@localhost:7054
```

The result is :

```
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:46244 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: Failed to connect to LDAP server over TCP at localhost:389: LDAP Result Code 200 "": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:389: connect: connection refused"
```

The LDAP is setup and functionning correctly, when sollicitated in CLI and via PHPLdapAdmin, an LDAP Browser, using the same credentials.

This is a bit of the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:

```
ldap:
  enabled: true
  url: ldap://cn=admin,dc=example:admin@localhost:389/dc=example
  userfilter: (uid=%s)
tls:
  enabled: false
  certfiles:
  client:
    certfile: noclientcert
    keyfile:
attribute:
  names: ['uid','member']
  converters:
    - name: hf.Revoker
      value: attr("uid") =~ "revoker*"
  maps:
    groups:
      - name: example
      value: peer
```

Anyone could help ?
Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues here:

First is more related with docker rather than fabric-ca. You have to set `netowrk_mode` to `host` to remove network isolation between the container and the Docker host. Then your docker container will see OpenLDAP located on Docker host

Please look into sample `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
 fabric-ca-server:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.1.0
  container_name: fabric-ca-server
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  volumes:
    - ./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start'
  network_mode: host
```

More about docker network you can find here: https://docs.docker.com/network/

When network issue will be resolved,  you have also to modify userfilter to relate with admin prefix so it should looks like this: `userfilter: (cn=%s)` If userfilter will not be repaired then you will get info that admin cannot be found in LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

I did not using the local LDAP server, instead I am using the one line for the quick test...
http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

However I am still getting the error as well.

My fabric-ca-server-config.yaml is

```
ldap:
   enabled: true
   url: ldap://cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com:password@ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com
   tls:
      certfiles:
      client:
         certfile:
         keyfile:
   # Attribute related configuration for mapping from LDAP entries to Fabric CA attributes
   attribute:
      names: ['uid','member']
      converters:
         - name: hf.Revoker
           value: attr("uid") =~ "revoker*"
      maps:
         groups:
            - name:
              value:
```

And I run it by:

```
fabric-ca-server start -c fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
```

I saw logs:

```
Successfully initialized LDAP client
```

Here is the screenshot for phpLDAPAdmin:
[image] 
I am using the same script for testing:

```
$fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com:password@localhost:7054

$fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com:password@localhost:7054
```

But still not good, getting something like:

```
POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: User 'uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com' does not exist in LDAP directory"
```